# QT: Creating extension methods

Tags: c++, qt

EDIT: not currently possible, but being talked about in the C++ community.

*** I am new QT(C++) but have a C# background. Please forgive me, if this is not something done in QT.

I wanted to know if there is a way to create extension methods with QT(C++), much similar to what you can do C#?

**Edit:**
My objective is to reduce the nested function calls as they are. This is to avoid going to the trouble of creating a FilePath class, where the the QString method is overloaded to hide the formatting.

Here is an example of what I want to do.

I have a string that contains a system path. I use the `QDir::fromNativeSeparators`to escape the string for usage in the `QFILE` object.

Is there a way to create a static utilities class that would allow for the following?

```
QString Src = "E:/dfdf/dfdf/";
QFile file(Src.NativeSep());
```

Comment: it is difficult to see what you want to achieve. Can you focus your efforts on explaining that?

Comment: You mean, detect the separator?

Comment: basically you want to know if there is a decorator pattern (concept behind C# extension method ) designed in Qt or c++?

Comment: This is also known as Unified Function Call Syntax or Unified Call Syntax and [has been proposed](http://isocpp.org/files/papers/N4174.pdf) for C++.

Comment: Ah, well it is nice to see that talks are in place. Thank you for the information @sjdowling.